# Get WPF TextBox Row and Column Position

Tags: wpf, textbox

I've been searching and the solutions here work for getting the row and column position of the cursor in a WPF text box until the row number is greater than 16,311.  After that, the column is a negative value.

```
    private void SetTextFileCursorPosition()
    {
        var caretIndex = TextFile.CaretIndex;
        var row = TextFile.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(caretIndex);
        var col = caretIndex - TextFile.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(row);
        CursorPosition = $"{col + 1}, {row + 1}";
    }
```

Comment: If you are referring to a multi-line textbox control, under what condition would you ever be allowing something with over 16,311 lines of data, let alone the columns indicating a small novel being written in a textbox.  For what purpose do you really need the row/col?

Comment: I'm developing a data viewer for downloads to my company's retail stores.  In some cases, the files being downloaded contain hundreds of thousands of lines.  I want to display the row/col position of the cursor within the control.

Comment: What font and font size are you using in your application? I wonder if that has any effect on things.

Comment: I'm giving the user an option to increase or decrease the font size but using Courier New as the font family because it needs to be a monospace font.  I'll test your latest solution with different sizes and make sure it still works.

Comment: I confirmed that the font size messes with the column position when the font size is less than 10 and the error occurs at different points depending on the font size. As long as the font size >= 10, it looks like it works fine.  I'm just going to have that as a known issue in this app until a patch comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange behavior. Even pouring through the .NET source code, I couldn't quite figure out exactly why this was happening. I've spent some time writing up my research and have submitted it as a bug in the .NET framework.

Here is the link to the bug report:
[System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex returns increasingly incorrect values for larger line numbers](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2961#issue-610501610)

But I'll include a summary of what I found:

My experience was a little different than yours. In my tests, everything works fine until I get to line 8,512. Starting at that line `GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex` seems to start returning the starting index of the *next* line, instead of the one being requested. Meaning, instead of giving me the start of 8,512, it was giving me the start of 8,513.

Testing with larger numbers of lines, I found that at line 25,536, `GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex` starts skipping *two* lines, instead returning the start of line 25,538. The number of line skips increases to 3 at line 42,560 and then to 4 at line 59,584.

This reveals a pattern: every 17,024 lines, the number of skipped lines increases by 1. The pattern starts at line 8,512, because it is 17,024 / 2 (half).

I can't explain why this happens exaclty, but the above provides some good documentation on the behavior. And below, I've put together some code to work around the problem.

You can work around this to a drgree:

```
var caretIndex = TextFile.CaretIndex;
var line = TextFile.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(caretIndex);
var colStart = TextFile.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(line);
var pos = caretIndex - colStart;

int posAdj = pos;
int lineAdj = line;

while (posAdj < 0)
{
    posAdj = TextFile.GetLineLength(lineAdj) + posAdj;
    lineAdj--;
}

CursorPosition = $"{posAdj + 1}, {line + 1}"; //NOT lineAdj
```

The above adds on the length of previous lines until it reaches a positive value, effectively adding in the skipped lines. This should work no matter how long the text is, and should even keep working after they (hopefully) patch the bug (since then `pos` should never be `< 0`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that didn't solve the problem, just moved it.  The issue now occurs at line 48,936 which is the previous position * 3.00018.  caretIndex = 2152803;  row = 48936; col = -88;

Comment: @KeithR I've updated my answer a bit, after spending way more time on this than I thought. It's definitly a bug. What's interesting is that mine starts skipping one line at line 8,512, then starts skipping two lines at 25,536- exactly 3 times as many lines later. Yours is actually exacly 3x as well if you start from the first line where the error occures, instead of the last correct line.

Comment: @KeithR Okay, this should be the last update. I've now provided code that should always output the right caret position.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  That appears to be working.  You're the best!

Comment: @KeithR You're welcome- from one Keith to another. Also, if you want the bug to actaully get fixed, you should probably go to the bug report I linked and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks again.  I didn't know to do that.